# How can JavaScript variable read value from a database or XML ( or other) files? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, database

I have a JavaScript file which has a variable as such:

```
var ads = new Array;
ads[0] = "/images/banners/buttonLO_apr.jpg";
...
```

How can I provide ads[0] a value from a database or an XML file or any other files?
I cannot make major changes on the JavaScript file.

Comment: You should either make an AJAX call to the server and retrieve the value, then assign it to ads[0], or you should already have the value on the server side and render the page with the value assigned to some element (perhaps an input hidden field) and your js reads from that field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do (that I know of):

- XML files - if the file has [Same Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of your script, then execute an AJAX call on that resource (you can do that fast and simple with a [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)), you'll get a string representation of the XML file which you can then start parsing and do all ya things.
- DB - There's no client-only solution (i.e. using just JS) I know of. You should put some cool Server Side script to accept your jQuery.get() and go and read the DB for ya. That's easily done with PHP but you'll need a PHP server to run that (for example [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/))